# Calculating means and sd for different groups

Tags: r, aggregate, average, reshape, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate means and standard deviations based on groups in a data.frame.

| Sample | Widht | Weight | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1.1 | 3.5 | 6.7 | 5.8 |
| 8.3 | 4.2 | 6.3 | 5.5 |
| A1.1 | 2.9 | 5.7 | 5.1 |
| 8.3 | 3.7 | 6.1 | 5.4 |

I have been trying with this code to calculate means and standard deviations for each column based on the sample. I have many more columns in the real data frame but all should be calculated based on the sample column.

`agdf<- aggregate(d.f, by=list(d.f$sample), function(x) c(mean = mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), sd = sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)))`

When I try this command I get this error message :

```
    Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
    Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
    Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
```

I have checked classes for each column and the "sample" column is a factor while the others are numeric. I am very new to R and I don´t really understand what is wrong and how I could solve it. I would really appreciate some ideas/help. Thank you.

Comment: please provide `dput(d.f)` of your data frame for help for the helpers/answerers

Comment: Note that in your code you are writing the `sample` column with lowercase "s", whereas in your screenshot it appears to be uppercase - that's a difference in R.

Comment: `agdf <- aggregate(.~sample, d.f, function(x) c(mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 1):

Always preferring the tidyverse way:

```
library(tidyverse)

agdf <- d.f %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), list(mean = mean, sd = sd), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Here we assume that you want to aggregate all your columns except the grouping column. If you only want to summarize a few columns, you can adjust the `across(...)` part.